# Extracting a dictionary from an RDD in Pyspark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark

This is a homework question:

I have an `RDD` which is a collection os tuples. I also have function which returns a dictionary from each input tuple. Somehow, the opposite of reduce function.

With map, I can easily go from a `RDD` of tuples to a `RDD` of dictionaries. But, since a dictionary is a collection of (key, value) pairs, I would like to convert the `RDD` of dictionaries into an `RDD` of (key, value) tuples with each dictionary contents.

That way, if my `RDD` contains 10 tuples, then I get an `RDD` containing 10 dictionaries with 5 elements (for example), and finally I get an `RDD` of 50 tuples.

I assume this has to be possible but, how? (Maybe the problem is that I don't know how this operation is called in English)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess what you want is just a `flatMap`:

```
dicts = sc.parallelize([{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 3, "baz": -1, "bar": 5}])
dicts.flatMap(lambda x: x.items())
```

`flatMap` takes a function from a element of RDD to iterable and then concatenates the results. Another name for the same type of operation outside the Spark context is `mapcat`:

```
>>> from toolz.curried import map, mapcat, concat, pipe
>>> from itertools import repeat
>>> pipe(range(4), mapcat(lambda i: repeat(i, i + 1)), list)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

or going step by step:

```
>>> pipe(range(4), map(lambda i: repeat(i, i + 1)), concat, list)
[0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

The same thing using `itertools.chain`

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> pipe((repeat(i, i + 1) for i in  range(4)), chain.from_iterable, list)
>>> [0, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: Sure! Could you please explain what is the difference between flatMap and map then? I didn't think flatMap was for these situations...

Comment: `flatMap`applies a function which returns a collection to all elements of this RDD and then flattens the results. Take a look at Scala `Rdd.flatMap` signature which simplified looks like this: `(f: (T) ⇒ TraversableOnce[U]): RDD[U]`

Comment: I added some non-Spark examples. I hope these will be helpful.

Answer (score 18):

My 2 cents:

There is a PairRDD function named "collectAsMap" that returns a dictionary from a RDD.

Let me show you an example:

```
sample = someRDD.sample(0, 0.0001, 0)
sample_dict = sample.collectAsMap()
print sample.collect()
print sample_dict

[('hi', 4123.0)]
{'hi': 4123.0}
```

Documentation [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.6.2/api/core/spark/PairRDDFunctions.html)

Hope it helps!
Regards!

Comment: Very handy. Thanks. Note this doesn't work on an RDD that's just a list. It needs to be tuples as shown above.

Comment: This would be a clearer example: 
`dicts = sc.parallelize([{"foo": 1, "bar": 2}, {"foo": 3, "baz": -1, "bar": 5}]); print(result.collect()); print(result.collectAsMap())`


And this snippet, the same as yours, show the difference between `.collect()` and `.collectAsMap()`.